# Create directory listing in Windows commandline with Special characters

Tags: windows-10, command-line

How do I create a directory listing on the commandline contaning the correct character setting, meaning, Umlauts like äöü are still correct, if I open the output in an editor?

I tried

```
dir /b > listing.txt
```

which looks fine to me, but all Umlauts are replaced with some broken character like `´´`

Is there a way to set the output to UTF-8 or such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start the Command Line interpreter with parameter /u (like cmd /u) you will probably achieve what you want.
Solution is not mine but found elsewhere on superuser;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905740/incorrect-encoding-after-redirecting-dir-output-to-a-file

You may also want to use the /ad switch to list directories only.

Comment: thanks, that worked, although the resulting list.txt dowsn't seem to havve a BOM, so I have to open it and save it once as UTF-8 again, te make it ready for other programs (i.e. word)